# Elasticsearch start error on Ubuntu nginx server

Tags: magento, magento2, vue-storefront

I have setup elasticsearch on Ubuntu nginx server. But after successfully installed when i tried to start elasticsearch then this error show: "elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'."

I have tried a lot to solve this error. But no one suitable answered are met. Please suggest me the solution to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The most-often problem with vue-storefront and elasticsearch is that it comes with default ElasticSearch config. This config,however, comes with the 2GB RAM allocation for elasticsearch service.

When you start your elasticsearch service you need to have unallocated/unused 2GB RAM on your system, otherwise it will fail to start and run.

If you do not have enough ram to do this. there are two things you can do:

- provide the service with less memory
- create a swap partition so it can write excessive RAM allocation there). This is not advised in the long run, however.